# looking for a solution to deploy node -js files in firebase

Tags: google-cloud-functions, eslint, firebase-tools

```
=== Deploying to 'corechipadminbackend'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help

need to solve this error and deploy the node-js files in firebase.

=== Deploying to 'corechipadminbackend'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

need solution soon